# Grouping Algorithm Speed Issues - Random swapping of pandas rows is slow

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, sorting

I've developed an application that helps overcome a common problem encountered at my work, and increases output quality and saves considerable time. Some employees are tasked with splitting groups of trainees (usually about 25-60 people in total), into several sub-groups (3-5). We would like these sub-groups to be optimally balanced along several trainee attributes. For simplicity, the most important attributes are the results of a pre-training test score, gender, and country of origin.

My application stores each sub-group as a pandas dataframe, so if there are 30 trainees, each sub-group dataframe has shape (9,3), with the trainee attributes and unique trainee identifier as columns. The algorithm used to sort into groups uses a utility function (with user-defined weights on attributes) and random assignment to find balanced sub-groups. On each iteration, a random member of each sub-group is swapped with a random member of an adjacent sub-group, and the utility function is calculated to return a score. If a particular grouping returns the lowest score for a certain number of swaps in a row (in my example 200), the grouping is found to be optimal. This entire process is repeated a designated number of times (say, 5) to find the best grouping and avoid problems with local minimums. Here's the code for the utility function and the swapping section of the algorithm:

```
###utility function
    def score_diff(first_df,second_df,third_df): # desired scores determined by overall group
        return (w_1*(abs(first_df['Grade/10.00'].mean() - desired_testscore)) + w_2*(abs(first_df['Female'].mean()-desired_genderbal)) + w_3*(abs(first_df['Country'].nunique() - opt_countrybal))) +\
           (w_1*(abs(second_df['Grade/10.00'].mean() - desired_testscore)) + w_2*(abs(second_df['Female'].mean()-desired_genderbal)) + w_3*(abs(second_df['Country'].nunique() - opt_countrybal))) +\
           (w_1*(abs(third_df['Grade/10.00'].mean() - desired_testscore)) + w_2*(abs(third_df['Female'].mean()-desired_genderbal)) + w_3*(abs(third_df['Country'].nunique() - opt_countrybal)))

### Swapping
if num_groups == 3:
    for i in range(5): # repeat the algorithm 5 times to avoid local minimums
        score_top = score_diff(pd_1,pd_2,pd_3)
        pd_1_old,pd_2_old,pd_3_old = pd_1.copy(),pd_2.copy(),pd_3.copy()
        pd_1.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
        pd_2.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
        pd_3.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
        cont = True
        counter=0
        while cont:
            rand_num1 = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = len(pd_1))
            rand_num2 = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = len(pd_2))
            pd_1.loc[rand_num1,:], pd_2.loc[rand_num2,:] = pd_2.iloc[rand_num2,:].copy(), pd_1.iloc[rand_num1,:].copy()
            rand_num2 = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = len(pd_2))
            rand_num3 = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = len(pd_3))
            pd_2.iloc[rand_num2,:],pd_3.iloc[rand_num3,:] = pd_3.iloc[rand_num3,:].copy(), pd_2.iloc[rand_num2,:].copy()
            rand_num3 = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = len(pd_3))
            rand_num1 = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = len(pd_1))
            pd_3.iloc[rand_num3,:],pd_1.iloc[rand_num1,:] = pd_1.iloc[rand_num1,:].copy(), pd_3.iloc[rand_num3,:].copy()
            score_new = score_diff(pd_1,pd_2,pd_3)
            if score_new < score_top: 
                score_top = score_new
                pd_1_old,pd_2_old,pd_3_old = pd_1.copy(),pd_2.copy(),pd_3.copy()
                counter = 0 
            else: 
                counter+=1 
                if counter > sort_length:
                    pd_1_opt,pd_2_opt,pd_3_opt = pd_1_old.copy(),pd_2_old.copy(),pd_3_old.copy()
                    cont = False 
                else: 
                    continue
        if i != 0: 
            if score_diff(pd_1_old,pd_2_old,pd_3_old) < score_diff(pd_1_opt,pd_2_opt,pd_3_opt):
                pd_1_opt,pd_2_opt,pd_3_opt = pd_1_old.copy(),pd_2_old.copy(),pd_3_old.copy()
```

For my purposes, the algorithm works and the application effectively returns balanced sub-groups. The only problem is program speed, which typically takes between 20 seconds to a minute to run given my example here, depending on the number of trainees to sort and attributes. This isn't catastrophic, but given the size of the problem, I believe it is possible to run this much more quickly. Unsurprisingly, quick checks of the algorithm show that most of the speed issues are coming from the swaps between sub-groups, shown again here:

```
            rand_num1 = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = len(pd_1))
            rand_num2 = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = len(pd_2))
            pd_1.loc[rand_num1,:], pd_2.loc[rand_num2,:] = pd_2.iloc[rand_num2,:].copy(), pd_1.iloc[rand_num1,:].copy()
            rand_num2 = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = len(pd_2))
            rand_num3 = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = len(pd_3))
            pd_2.iloc[rand_num2,:],pd_3.iloc[rand_num3,:] = pd_3.iloc[rand_num3,:].copy(), pd_2.iloc[rand_num2,:].copy()
            rand_num3 = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = len(pd_3))
            rand_num1 = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = len(pd_1))
            pd_3.iloc[rand_num3,:],pd_1.iloc[rand_num1,:] = pd_1.iloc[rand_num1,:].copy(), pd_3.iloc[rand_num3,:].copy()
```

For my needs, the random assignment algorithm is sufficient, and I don't have plans to change it. However, I'm hoping I might get some suggestions into ways to overcome the speed issue introduced by the random swapping of rows of the pandas dataframes. It's this swapping of data in the rows that is introducing the speed issues. Is there perhaps a better way that this could be done within the context of the current algorithm?

Any suggestion on overcoming this challenge would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just forget pandas and use plain and simple simple python lists

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.